# 3 approaches to work with XML

Tags: c#, xml

I need to use different approaches when working with XML - LINQ to XML, streaming, DOM.

Can anybody give me examples of this approaches?

I just want to see what's the difference between this approaches.

Comment: 1) LinqToXml (aka XDocument/XElement) 2) Streaming: XmlReader/XmlWriter 3) DOM: XmlDocument/XmlElement.   Google these keywords independently, there is already a *wealth* of information/tutorials available.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I want. Add it as an answer and I mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about Linq, but streaming vs. dom are different in that a DOM approach parses entire XML documents in to memory before the user-level API becomes active, while the stream based approach raises "events" during the low-level parsing routine.  Consider what would happen if you processed a long XML file with a syntax error at the very end of the file,  with DOM vs. Streamed; the DOM based approach would error before your program could "get at the data", while the streamed based approach would have already generated a long list of events before the error gets thrown.

The DOM approach means the API can do "whole document lookups", for example in DOM/Xpath you can say "//div" to mean "all div elements in the document", this is much harder / impossible in a streamed approach.  On the other hand, streamed processing tends to use less memory, as only a small part of the XML document needs to be held in memory at one time.

Examples of APIs using these approaches are SAX/XmlReader for stream based, DOM/XSLT for DOM based.